# Spring data hibernate serialize item properties according to method

Tags: spring, hibernate, jackson, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a question. 
Lets imagine, we have an entity of Hotel. That entity contains for example **id, name, Country object reference, theme foto path and list of other photo patches**.

I'm using the Spring boot JPA + jackson. So repositories are like...

```
@Repository
public interface HotelRepository extends CrudRepository<HotelEntity, Long> {
    List<HotelEntity> findTop3ByCountryOrderByPriorityDesc(CountryEntity country);
}
```

Is there any possibility to annotate entity fields with some jackson to tell Spring boot- "Hey, if you use this repository method (for example that findTop3ByCountryOrderByPriorityDesc method), take just name, id and theme photo.
(And this approach would be used in all entities and methods). Something like

```
@JsonSerializeClasses({"top3Hotels", "hotels"})    
String name;
```

And usage in repositorz

```
@JsonSerializeClassesUsage({top3Hotels})
List<HotelEntity> findTop3ByCountryOrderByPriorityDesc(CountryEntitycountry);
```

(This method would return list of hotel entities that contains just names).

Note: It can work in a "negative" way too. So if I annotate some field with some "class in class", this field would not be included in return object from method, that has not this "inner class" included in its annotation.

Is this possible in Spring data with jackson?

Or I really have to return objects and in cases i dont want some properities, I have to iterate over them and "null" it manually?

Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to do it automatically. What I can suggest to you is to create a custom Native Query where you can take only the needed fields and reverse them in a custom DTO object. In this way you created a specified method in your JPARepository. This method is able in taking out only the fields you need and serialize them opportunely

Comment: Use projections as explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) in the reference guide.